# How to build a Ballerina project with tests

Tags: testing, ballerina

Is there a recommended approach for building the ballerina project only if the test cases are passing?
`bal build` command does not execute test cases prior to build the project.

Currently I tried executing `bal test` first and then `bal build` to verify that the test cases are passing. Is there a straight forward way to do this rather than doing it in two individual steps.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to run tests before build is to run `bal test` and then `bal build`. There is no straight forward method to do this so running them in two individual steps is the recommended approach.

Related spec discussion: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/966#issuecomment-954157263